# Vias or traces through two pins of e.g. resistors on a PCB?

Tags: pcb, via, trace

I made the design below in KiCad. It's for me a test to see if I can solder SOT23, 0604, 0805 and 1205 components.

Someone said it is not a good idea to make traces between two pins of a component (see all blue circles,) however, if I do not do that, I need a lot of vias, since I cannot route them around the component because on both sides traces move away from the component.

Is there a good way to tackle this? Or what should I prefer? The way below or using vias?

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95452/discussion-on-question-by-michel-keijzers-vias-or-traces-through-two-pins-of-e-g).  Any conclusions reached should be edited back into the question and/or any answer(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is generally nothing wrong with routing between pads of components, provided trace width and clearance rules are followed. In fact, in many designs it is recommended to use 0 ohm resistors to jump one trace over another without needing a via to another layer.

In your case, as others have noted, you do not need to use traces for ground. It is preferable in that case to use vias directly to the ground plane/pour to minimize inductance. The same often goes for power connections, as well.

Comment: Interesting idea to use 0 ohm resistors for that :-)